# Android - Creating an activity just for sharing

Tags: android

How would I go about displaying the contents of a simple share intent in an Activity? I want to add a dedicated 'Sharing' activity in my app instead of just having a button in the corner that opens up a little menu.

So, where the normal sharing menu looks like this:

[image: android share]
<sub>(source: [android.com](https://developer.android.com/images/training/sharing/share-text-screenshot.png))</sub>

I'd like to have those options (ie gmail, twitter, etc) right in the activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to have those options (ie gmail, twitter, etc) right in the activity.

The simplest standard approach is to use a `ShareActionProvider` in your action bar.

If you wish to roll your own mechanism, create the `Intent` that represents the "sharing" option, then use `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()` to find all the matches. Present those in a list to the user, and when the user selects one, update the `Intent` with the `ComponentName` of the chosen activity (converting it from an implicit `Intent` to an explicit `Intent`), and use `startActivity()` (or, if relevant, `startActivityForResult()`) to start it.

[This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Introspection/Launchalot) implements a home screen-style launcher using the same basic approach:

```
/***
  Copyright (c) 2008-2012 CommonsWare, LLC
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
    https://commonsware.com/Android
*/

package com.commonsware.android.launchalot;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Launchalot extends ListActivity {
  AppAdapter adapter=null;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    PackageManager pm=getPackageManager();
    Intent main=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);

    main.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    List<ResolveInfo> launchables=pm.queryIntentActivities(main, 0);

    Collections.sort(launchables,
                     new ResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator(pm)); 

    adapter=new AppAdapter(pm, launchables);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v,
                                 int position, long id) {
    ResolveInfo launchable=adapter.getItem(position);
    ActivityInfo activity=launchable.activityInfo;
    ComponentName name=new ComponentName(activity.applicationInfo.packageName,
                                         activity.name);
    Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
    i.setComponent(name);

    startActivity(i);    
  }

  class AppAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ResolveInfo> {
    private PackageManager pm=null;

    AppAdapter(PackageManager pm, List<ResolveInfo> apps) {
      super(Launchalot.this, R.layout.row, apps);
      this.pm=pm;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                          ViewGroup parent) {
      if (convertView==null) {
        convertView=newView(parent);
      }

      bindView(position, convertView);

      return(convertView);
    }

    private View newView(ViewGroup parent) {
      return(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false));
    }

    private void bindView(int position, View row) {
      TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.label);

      label.setText(getItem(position).loadLabel(pm));

      ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon);

      icon.setImageDrawable(getItem(position).loadIcon(pm));
    }
  }
}
```

In your case:

- Change the `Intent` to be your desired `ACTION_SEND` (or whatever) structure
- Implement whatever you want for presenting the options to the user (this activity uses a `ListView`)
- Deal with the cases where there are no matches and one match (which are virtually impossible for a home screen launcher and therefore are skipped in this sample)

Comment: This actually works better than I could have hoped. This way I can customize each Intent. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Get List of Packages that can handle specific intent:

```
    PackageManager pm = ctx.getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> handlers = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.GET_RESOLVED_FILTER);
```

Then show this list in your way and start specific package on click for example like that:

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
//THIS IS ONLY PSEUDOCODE showing how it should work in general
Intent launchIntent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(ResolveInfo.gresolvePackageName);
context.startActivity(launchIntent);
```